# What master URL to use for a Spark running in Kubernetes?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-spark-sql, minikube

I have a spark cluster running in `minikube`:

```
$ k get pods                                                                                                                                              
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
spark-master-0   1/1     Running   0          7d
spark-worker-0   1/1     Running   0          7d
spark-worker-1   1/1     Running   0          7d
```

I have port-forwarded to master:

```
$ k port-forward spark-master-0 8080:8080                                                                                                                   
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
```

I am trying to create a `JavaSparkSession` but I'm not sure what master URL to use:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("???")
    .setAppName("test-spark");
SparkSession.builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate();
```

Tried the following that didn't work

- `"local"`
- `"localhost:8080`
- `http://localhost:8080`
- `spark://localhost:8080`
- (from one of the answers) `k8s://http://192.168.1.2:8080`
- (from one of the answers) `k8s://https://kubernetes:443`

None of them work. Get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: '<MASTER URL FROM LIST ABOVE>'
```

What master URL do I use? thanks

**EDIT**
Url `spark://192.168.58.2:7077` works partially. Get the following error:

```
2023-04-12T14:53:50.220-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [           main] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@49c1e294{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2023-04-12T14:53:50.255-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [er-threadpool-0] s.d.c.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint : Connecting to master spark://192.168.58.2:7077...
2023-04-12T14:54:10.265-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [er-threadpool-0] s.d.c.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint : Connecting to master spark://192.168.58.2:7077...
2023-04-12T14:54:30.264-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [er-threadpool-0] s.d.c.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint : Connecting to master spark://192.168.58.2:7077...
2023-04-12T14:54:50.272-07:00  WARN 40229 --- [           main] o.a.s.s.c.StandaloneSchedulerBackend     : Application ID is not initialized yet.
2023-04-12T14:54:50.272-07:00 ERROR 40229 --- [on-retry-thread] o.a.s.s.c.StandaloneSchedulerBackend     : Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
2023-04-12T14:54:50.284-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [p-spark-context] o.s.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Stopped Spark@7b6141f0{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2023-04-12T14:54:50.286-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [p-spark-context] org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI              : Stopped Spark web UI at http://mgc14dlpj2f2.lan:4040
2023-04-12T14:54:50.289-07:00  INFO 40229 --- [p-spark-context] o.a.s.s.c.StandaloneSchedulerBackend     : Shutting down all executors
...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(Object, scala.reflect.ClassTag)" because the return value of "org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.driverEndpoint()" is null
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
k8s://https://{MasterIp}:{Port}
```

**UPDATE:**
Im with K8s, in your case it should be spark, also I checked and I'm not using HTTPS after k8s

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name")
    .setMaster("spark://192.168.58.2:8080").set("spark.ui.port","8080");
```

Comment: Same issue: Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'k8s://https://192.168.58.2:8080'

Comment: Thanks, this kinda worked so I have accepted your answer. however, it is now timing out and I'd appreciate your inputs on it: Connecting to master spark://192.168.58.2:7077... (eventually errors out) 
thanks!

Comment: When it happens ? is it after creating new SparkConf() ? when you try to get/create the configuration ? any logs to paste here ?

Comment: sure, updated question with logs. thanks!

Comment: Give this a try: start a spark shell by using 1) bin/spark-shell --master spark://192.168.58.2:7077 2) if #1 works... does bin/spark-shell --help show something ?

Comment: #1 didn't work: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.ApplicationInfo.attempts()" because the return value of "org.apache.spark.status.AppStatusListener.appInfo()" is null